# Воспроизведение музыки в C#

Tags: c#, wpf, аудио

Как в WPF приложении из кода воспроизвести музыкальный трек mp3, если известен путь к нему?

Comment: Что за приложение вы пишете? WinForms, WPF, UWP? Какой тип файла вы хотите воспроизвести? Уточните.

Comment: @andreycha,в WPF приложении необходимо проиграть .мр3 файл

Comment: Впредь включайте всю необходимую информацию в вопрос сразу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать класс [SoundPlayer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=vs.110).aspx) - в WinForms.
Или функцию [PlaySound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173187.aspx).
Или [WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562692(v=vs.85).aspx)
А в WPF приложениях - класс [MediaPlayer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var player = new MediaPlayer();
player.MediaFailed += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show("Error");
player.Open(new Uri("../../Sound.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
player.Play();
```